# Failing to install pcaprub in order to install packet-fu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libpcap

I am trying to install packet-fu in ruby. Up to this point I have successfuly executed the following steps:

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

But when I type:

```
gem install -r pcaprub
```

I get the following error:

```
# gem install pcaprub
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pcaprub:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pcaprub-0.13.1/ext/pcaprub_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby -r ./siteconf20230625-212902-9pqf73.rb extconf.rb

[*] Running checks for pcaprub_c code...
platform is x86_64-linux-gnu
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.7
        --with-pcap-dir
        --without-pcap-dir
        --with-pcap-include
        --without-pcap-include=${pcap-dir}/include
        --with-pcap-lib
        --without-pcap-lib=${pcap-dir}/lib
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:471:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:613:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1124:in `block in have_header'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:971:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:970:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1123:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:82:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/pcaprub-0.13.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pcaprub-0.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/pcaprub-0.13.1/gem_make.out
```

I've spent hours on this and would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Pay attention to this line in your log: `checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, gcc was bit installed. Reinstalling it solved the issue.